# Gsuite Application - How to work with service accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, integration, service-accounts, google-workspace

I am working on a project which needs to be integrated with Gsuite.
I am using .NET Core & EF Core for my project.
I have no idea how to integrate Gsuite with my application.

I've done lots of script that works with Google API's but I put all it needs manually(service account json file etc.).
Now, I want to make an application where users clicks the integrate with gsuite button.

Here is the scenario:

1) User clicks the "integrate with gsuite" button.

2) A service account is created with needed scopes in their GCP.

The result should be like this:

[image: Example]

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: G Suite is integrated with GCP. Can you be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish (Edit your question with details).

Comment: @JohnHanley I've included an example image of expected outcome.